# how do i lock access to a bool with a mutex?

Tags: c++, multithreading, sdl-2

**solved!: im copying the instance of Map in the new Thread an dont use the reference.**

im learning how to use multiple threads. For this im programing a little game where i want the game to run in the main thread and the next chunk of the level shall be loaded in another thread. for this i set up a mutex around a vector to tell the loading thread what to load next. inside this mutex i also have a boolean to tell the thread when tu terminate.

**initialising thread in Map::Map()**

```
pending_orders_mutex = SDL_CreateMutex();
can_process_order = SDL_CreateCond();
chunk_loader_thread = SDL_CreateThread(Map::chunk_loader,"chunk_loader_thread",(void*)this);
```

**loading thread**

```
int Map::chunk_loader(void * data)
{
    Map map = *(Map*)data;
    bool kill_this_thread = false;

    Chunk_Order actual_order;
    actual_order.load_graphics = false;
    actual_order.x = 0;
    actual_order.y = 0;



    while (!kill_this_thread)
    {
        SDL_LockMutex(map.pending_orders_mutex);            // lock mutex
        printf("3-kill_chunk_loader_thread: %d\n", map.kill_chunk_loader_thread);
        kill_this_thread = map.kill_chunk_loader_thread;
        printf("4-kill_chunk_loader_thread: %d\n", map.kill_chunk_loader_thread);
        if (!kill_this_thread)
        {
            if (map.pending_orders.size())
            {
                actual_order = map.pending_orders.back();
                map.pending_orders.pop_back();
                printf("in thread processing order\n");
            }
            else
            {
                printf("in thread waiting for order\n");
                SDL_CondWait(map.can_process_order, map.pending_orders_mutex);
            }
        }
        SDL_UnlockMutex(map.pending_orders_mutex);          // unlock mutex

        //load actual order
    }
    printf("thread got killed\n");
    return 0;
}
```

**killing the thread (main thread)**

```
SDL_LockMutex(pending_orders_mutex);            // lock mutex
  printf("setting kill command\n");
  printf("1-kill_chunk_loader_thread: %d\n", kill_chunk_loader_thread);
kill_chunk_loader_thread = true;                // send kill command
  printf("2-kill_chunk_loader_thread: %d\n", kill_chunk_loader_thread);
SDL_CondSignal(can_process_order);              // signal that order was pushed
SDL_UnlockMutex(pending_orders_mutex);          // unlock mutex

SDL_WaitThread(chunk_loader_thread, NULL);
```

**console output**

```
3-kill_chunk_loader_thread: 0
4-kill_chunk_loader_thread: 0
in thread waiting for order
setting kill command
1-kill_chunk_loader_thread: 0
2-kill_chunk_loader_thread: 1
3-kill_chunk_loader_thread: 0
4-kill_chunk_loader_thread: 0
in thread waiting for order
```

why does the mainthread not change the "kill_chunk_loader_thread" boolean in the loading thread?

Comment: Do you have a solid understanding of how mutexes work? You don't protect access by locking a variable, you protect concurrent thread access by mutual exclusion: whenever the variable is accessed, make sure that thread takes a specific lock for it first.

Comment: Upvoting for the use of mutexes while you're learning multithreading. Not everyone does --- *looks at myself*

Comment: When do you assign `map.kill_chunk_loader_thread`, to 0 or 1?  I'd put breakpoints on those and check that that's getting set as expected

Comment: Read some [POSIX thread tutorial](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/). Consider perhaps using [std::atomic_bool](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic) and its [load](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/load) & [store](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/store)

Comment: Expanding on what Josh Detwiler said, if you want to protect a variable, or a _group_ of related variables, it's up to you to make sure that there's no place in your code that uses the variable(s) when the mutex is not locked. Also, it's up to you to make sure that it's always the _same_ mutex. (Locking the wrong mutex is a common rookie mistake.)

Comment: @JoshDetwiler im not realy sure if i fully understood it. I read somewhere that only one thread should read and write a variable at a time. so i put a mutex around every part that reads and writes that variable. is that the right way ?

Comment: @UKMonkey i expanded my code in the question a little bit more. I will try using breakpoints

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch thanks i will look into it.

Comment: `Map map = *(Map*)data;` that is really weird. Looks like you operate on different copies of `map` in different threads?

Comment: @just_some_dude This might help you better understand locks and thread safety: [Multithreading & Locking](https://courses.cs.vt.edu/~cs3214/spring2018/lectures/Lecture-Multithreading-Locking.pdf).

Comment: @keltar im stupid. Your right im copying map there and that  explains why kill_chunk_loader_thread is never set to true in the copy. Thanks a lot. Does someone know how i should go about marking the solution ?

Comment: @JoshDetwiler Thanks! i will read what ever i can get my hands on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you should try to upload a minimal complete program in the question.

Its look like you set `kill_chunk_loader_thread = true`

but you didn't set `map.kill_chunk_loader_thread = true`

the section of `map` declaration is missig from your question, but I guess you didn't use a reference to the local or global variable, or you just perform struct  copy so when you change one struct the other doesn't been affected at all.

**EDIT:**

`Map map = *(Map*)data;` copies the `map` structure (default copy constructor, I guess) so from now on if the source map change the copy won't.

You should keep work with the pointer, like this: `Map* pMap = (Map*)data;`
and check the pointer like this: `kill_this_thread = pMap->kill_chunk_loader_thread;` so you read from the source map.

Comment: expanded the sourcecode a little. im giving a pointer to the instance of the Map class to the thread. its the one and only instance of this class.